# Tensorflow warm_start even if checkpoint found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, transfer-learning

I noticed that my variables tagged for warm_start are getting warm started if there are checkpoints in my model dir or not. Is there a way to not warm start, if there are already checkpoints? Or does it have anything to to with the fact that I exclude these variables from training?

I'm using using warm_start in a custom estimator for initializing inception_v4 from which I use one of the last layers as input for my model.

```
ws = tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings(ckpt_to_initialize_from=self.warm_start_dir,
                                             vars_to_warm_start='.*InceptionV4.*')
```

At the moment I also exclude them from training:

```
train_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
exc_vars = [var for var in train_vars if 'InceptionV4' not in var.name]
tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimatorSpec(mode, loss=mean_loss, train_op=optimizer.
                                       minimize(mean_loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(), var_list=exc_vars))
```

But I also want take a run at not excluding them, which would be a bigger problem then.